# Displaying generated image via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, printing

I have form where i can write text. I want this text to be generated on image. I have it and it works, i'm `using imagepng($im)`. The problem is that i need to print that image, and have a "print" button. Because of `header('Content-Type: image/png')` i cant use html on page where i generate it so i would like to use ajax. This is my actual code which well is little mixed, i tried something with base64 but never used it and i failed. Acutally my code isnt even showing errors(shows with datatype json). I dont really know how to do it. Didn't found it anywhere. Please help i don't know what to do ;_;

Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
  $( "#form_formularz" ).submit(function(e)
  {
   var data=JSON.stringify($('form').serialize())
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({

    type: 'post',
    url: 'http://example.com/transfer_generator.php',
    data: data,
    error: function(a,b){console.log(a);console.log(b)},
    success: function(cbdata){
      console.log(data);
      console.log(cbdata);
      $('#form_image').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + cbdata + '" />');
    }
   });
  });
 });
});
</script>
<div id="form_image">
</div>
```

EDIT: 
changed "`succes`" to "`success`" and added `cbdata` in s`uccess: function(){`

There is '

```
// Set the content-type
header('Content-Type: image/png');

// Create the image
$im = ImageCreateFromPNG( "image.png" );

/* adding some text, everything okay */

imagepng($im);
```

I tried to add echo 'base64_encode(imagepng($im));' but didnt work for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two errors in your code.  Fix those before debugging further.

1. The `success` method is misspelled.
2. The `success` method has no `cbdata` argument.  Where are you declaring this?

Try the following:

```
...
    success: function(cbdata){
      console.log(data);
      console.log(cbdata);
      $('#form_image').html('<img src="data:image/png;base64,' + cbdata + '" />');
    }
...
```

EDIT: In response to your edit, do the following in your PHP file:

1. Remove the `header` statement.
2. You need to send back the string contents of the base64 encoded image.  Something like this:

   ```
   $fileName = 'my-temp-image.png';
   imagepng($im, $fileName);
   imagedestroy($im);
   $base64Image = base64_encode(file_get_contents($fileName));
   unlink($fileName);
   echo $base64Image;
   ```

Comment: Well that's something! But still don't know how to display an image. :(